# Using lxml.etree to transform XML using an XSL with XPATH 2.0 function(s)

Tags: python, xml, lxml, xslt-2.0, elementtree

```
import lxml.etree as ET

dom = ET.parse(xml_filename)
xslt = ET.parse(xsl_filename)
transform = ET.XSLT(xslt)
newdom = transform(dom)
print(ET.tostring(newdom, pretty_print=True))
```

Returns:

```
...
XSLTParseError: xsl:for-each : could not compile select expression
'year-from-dateTime($beginDate) to year-from-dateTime($endDate)'
```

I understand that this function is a XPATH 2.0 function, which I'm finding out is not supported by etree. I've heard about [elementpath](https://elementpath.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and I'm wondering if it has a similar function as [lxml.etree.XSLT](https://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree.XSLT-class.html) for transforms. I don't see any mention of XSLT in the elementpath docs.

Comment: You can try saxonica's SaxonC-HE (Home Edition): https://www.saxonica.com/download/c.xml It supports even XSLT 3.0

Comment: At this time, lxml only supports XSLT 1.0, so does not include `for-each`. Post your full XSLT as there may be alternative ways such as the [Muenchian Method](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html) to translate this iterative grouping construct to XSLT 1.0.

Comment: If you want to use XSLT 2 or 3 with Python consider SaxonC https://pypi.org/project/saxonche/.